How to prevent history.pushState from iFrame src change
For an existing <iframe> the src attribute gets changed with AlpineJS. How can I make the browser ignore this src change for the browser history?
My current (basic) iframe code:
<iframe :src="iframeSrc"></iframe>


Please post your code.

The answer lies in using a setTimeout() (even without an interval) before setting the new value, so the iframe gets destroyed and recreated instead of reused, which seems to prevent the history entry.
So this might look like this:
this.iframeSrc = ''; setTimeout(() => this.iframeSrc = '/new-source');

There are other ways which have been discussed on github/alpinejs

Have you tried doing history.pushState = () => null? If that doesn’t work then you probably need to monkey patch Alpine JS.

I'm sorry, where do I do that exactly? I added my current iframe code to the description.

Also I would still like to use pushState myself in all the other cases, except for the iframe src change

You can add it before you load the framework.

I solved it now with a setTimeout() for changing the iframe src

You might want to add an example here, incase anyone else has the same issue
